# How to close initiation workflow window?

Tags: 2010, workflow, initiation-form

I open a dialog  initiation window of my sequential workflow from ECB menu. There is a start button on it. When this button is clicked the workflow starts working and the dialog window stays open. How can I start the workflow and then close the window immediately? For example, start workflow asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. I use `SPWorkflowRunOptions.Asynchronous` :

```
Web.Site.WorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(workflowListItem, association, GetInitiationData(),SPWorkflowRunOptions.Asynchronous).
```

But there is other issue: workflow starts working after 3-5 minutes.